# copy without malloc in microjson

Tags: c, json

I read on the repository page of http://www.catb.org/esr/microjson/

> This code parses the largest subset of JSON that can be unpacked into
> static C structures, without using malloc(3).

I looked into its source code to understand how it was done, but not sure if I'm looking at the right place. Following is an excerpt from the repository.

```
char *lptr;
switch (cursor->type) {
        case t_integer:
            memcpy(lptr, &cursor->dflt.integer, sizeof(int));
}
```

---

**My Attempt**

How can the same be done assuming for the literal string in my example?

```
char json[] = "{\"name\": \"john\"}"
char *copy = NULL;
memcpy(copy, 9, 4); // john starts at 9 and has 4 characters length
```

---

**Edit - Attempt 2**

I tried this. is this better? It works.

```
char *substring(const char *start, long len, char *destination) {
    strncpy(destination, start, len);
    destination[len] = '\0';
    return destination;
}

char key[5];
substring(9, 4, key);
```

**Follow-up question**, can you do the same with a string array, without malloc?

Assigning different parts of a large string as items to an array?

Comment: The second code example is definitely not recommended.  Copying to a pointer that is not initialized with memory is undefined behavior and may cause a crash even on a good day.
If you want to say ... copy = json;   .....  that's OK, but is much different than invoking memcpy().

Comment: You must allocate the space somehow before copying data into it. You can use a VLA (Variable Length Array) if you don't have to adhere to old c standards. If you don't allocate the space, it may still compile and even run (sometimes) without error but will be prone to random crashes and data corruption.

Comment: The idea is that you use some static storage structure which data is then copied into. Attempt 2 is what is done here.